# Copy and Rename Files from sub-directories to different sub-directories based on two lists?

Tags: python

I have small problem to solve with python. I have 50k images stored within 20k folders. I have to move them into new folder structure that I created and rename these images. Here is the test environment with C:\TEST\SOURCE and C:\TEST\DESTINATION folder structure:
[image]

I have Src.csv that has one column with image paths like this:

```
C:\TEST\SOURCE\1\a.png
C:\TEST\SOURCE\2\b.jpg
C:\TEST\SOURCE\3\c.jpg
C:\TEST\SOURCE\4\d.jpg
C:\TEST\SOURCE\5\e.jpg
```

And I have Dest.csv that has one column with path where each image should go:

```
C:\TEST\DESTINATION\6\a.png
C:\TEST\DESTINATION\7\b.jpg
C:\TEST\DESTINATION\8\c.jpg
C:\TEST\DESTINATION\9\d.jpg
C:\TEST\DESTINATION\10\e.jpg
```

Here is what I have tried to do:

```
import csv
from shutil import copyfile

def load_paths(filename):
    pathdict = {}
    with open(filename) as csvfile:
        filereader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
        a = 0
        for row in filereader:
           pathdict[a] = ''.join(row)
           a += 1
        csvfile.close()
        return pathdict

srcpaths = load_paths('srcfile.csv')
dstpaths = load_paths('dstfile.csv')

for a in range(len(srcpaths)):
    copyfile(srcpaths[a],dstpaths[a])
```

I am able to make this to copy the files, however I am not sure how to rename them now. I am assuming I will need another list to reference to what name I will use. For example, I will have one csv with two column one with path and original name and second with new name? Would that work? And how would I rename these images in addition to code I have up there?

Update - The copying does not work properly. It is copying the images from 1 to 6, 2 to 7, 3 to 8, 4 to 9, 5 to 10 folders. So regardless how i specify it in my destination folder the script for some reason is copying the images as it reads first line for source and paste it to first line in destination folder.

What do i need to change?

Comment: What happens? Error messages? Does `load_paths` return the expected dictionaries (show them)? (Edit the question to answer)

Comment: If you have the full destination path including filename there is `os.path.dirname` to get the path without filename. Then you can `os.path.join` the destination directory with the new filename (without path). If the new filename isn't used by a file yet, renaming should work. Instead of this copying+renaming you can also construct the new destination path as described and copy to the path with new filename directly.

Comment: @Slavisha - You say it's copying file "1 to 6" etc. is that not what you wanted? Your `Dest.csv` file has the path `C:\TEST\DESTINATION\6\a.png` which I assumed is the destination for the first file in the `Src.csv`. Is that not what you want to happen? Simply change the `Dest.csv` file to have the path and filename you want the file to be copied to.

Comment: Yes however,if i would like to image a.jpg from C:\TEST\SOURCE\1\a.png to go to C:\TEST\DESTINATION\10\, even If I edit destination file to say C:\TEST\DESTINATION\10\a.png it still goes to C:\TEST\DESTINATION\6\

Comment: @Slavisha - I've updated my answer in response to your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put the new names in the destination csv file:

```
C:\TEST\DESTINATION\6\aaa.png
C:\TEST\DESTINATION\7\bcc.jpg
...
```

The files are renamed as they are copied.

If you prefer not to have to clean up the source folder, use the `move` function which also allows for renaming as the file is moved:

```
import csv
from shutil import move  # import move in place of copyfile
...
for a in range(len(srcpaths)):
    move(srcpaths[a],dstpaths[a])
```

**Update in response to your comment:**

Your code loads the two files in to separate lists, using an index to get the source and destination file paths. The only link between the files is the line number of the file. If I add line numbers to the files shown in your question:

```
"Src.csv"
[1] C:\TEST\SOURCE\1\a.png
[2] C:\TEST\SOURCE\2\b.jpg
[3] C:\TEST\SOURCE\3\c.jpg
[4] C:\TEST\SOURCE\4\d.jpg
[5] C:\TEST\SOURCE\5\e.jpg

"Dest.csv"
[1] C:\TEST\DESTINATION\6\a.png
[2] C:\TEST\DESTINATION\7\b.jpg
[3] C:\TEST\DESTINATION\8\c.jpg
[4] C:\TEST\DESTINATION\9\d.jpg
[5] C:\TEST\DESTINATION\10\e.jpg
```

Once read in they are "matched" using the list index (line number) so the `source --> destination` mapping will be:

```
[1] C:\TEST\SOURCE\1\a.png --> [1] C:\TEST\DESTINATION\6\a.png
[2] C:\TEST\SOURCE\2\b.jpg --> [2] C:\TEST\DESTINATION\7\b.jpg
[3] C:\TEST\SOURCE\3\c.jpg --> [3] C:\TEST\DESTINATION\8\c.jpg
[4] C:\TEST\SOURCE\4\d.jpg --> [4] C:\TEST\DESTINATION\9\d.jpg
[5] C:\TEST\SOURCE\5\e.jpg --> [5] C:\TEST\DESTINATION\10\e.jpg
```

If you want to move the file `C:\TEST\SOURCE\1\a.png` to the folder `10` you need to change the first line of your destination file to `C:\TEST\DESTINATION\10\a.png`. The linking *is not* based on the filenames.

To take it a step further, lets say you want to move *all* the files to folder `10`. Your `Dest.csv` file would contain:

```
[1] C:\TEST\DESTINATION\10\a.png
[2] C:\TEST\DESTINATION\10\b.jpg
[3] C:\TEST\DESTINATION\10\c.jpg
[4] C:\TEST\DESTINATION\10\d.jpg
[5] C:\TEST\DESTINATION\10\e.jpg
```

Comment: I have updated the original comment with problem I am facing with copying the files.